# Moment JS has 100 or so more timezones compared to PHP, bug? How do I get them in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm using Moment JS, and have just recently outputted the timezones listed using `this.$moment.tz.names()` in my Nuxt JS project. However, the timezones that my server has inside of the `timezone_identifiers_list` function in PHP seems to be about 100 or so less, and weirdly, it seems that some important ones are either missing from PHP, or not meant to be in Moment, such as:

> US/Central

Why would PHP not contain these missing timezones from Moment?

I'll attach a screenshot of the ones that appear to be outputted from Moment that aren't in PHP, wondering how I can get these timezones into that PHP list?

I've outputted the list of timezones from PHP into a string, because I'm going to have to compare the moment ones then and set a default if my timezone guess logic picks one that doesn't exist since I have a Laravel validation rule for timezone.

```js
const prodTimezones = JSON.parse("[\"Africa\\/Abidjan\",\"Africa\\/Accra\",\"Africa\\/Addis_Ababa\",\"Africa\\/Algiers\",\"Africa\\/Asmara\",\"Africa\\/Bamako\",\"Africa\\/Bangui\",\"Africa\\/Banjul\",\"Africa\\/Bissau\",\"Africa\\/Blantyre\",\"Africa\\/Brazzaville\",\"Africa\\/Bujumbura\",\"Africa\\/Cairo\",\"Africa\\/Casablanca\",\"Africa\\/Ceuta\",\"Africa\\/Conakry\",\"Africa\\/Dakar\",\"Africa\\/Dar_es_Salaam\",\"Africa\\/Djibouti\",\"Africa\\/Douala\",\"Africa\\/El_Aaiun\",\"Africa\\/Freetown\",\"Africa\\/Gaborone\",\"Africa\\/Harare\",\"Africa\\/Johannesburg\",\"Africa\\/Juba\",\"Africa\\/Kampala\",\"Africa\\/Khartoum\",\"Africa\\/Kigali\",\"Africa\\/Kinshasa\",\"Africa\\/Lagos\",\"Africa\\/Libreville\",\"Africa\\/Lome\",\"Africa\\/Luanda\",\"Africa\\/Lubumbashi\",\"Africa\\/Lusaka\",\"Africa\\/Malabo\",\"Africa\\/Maputo\",\"Africa\\/Maseru\",\"Africa\\/Mbabane\",\"Africa\\/Mogadishu\",\"Africa\\/Monrovia\",\"Africa\\/Nairobi\",\"Africa\\/Ndjamena\",\"Africa\\/Niamey\",\"Africa\\/Nouakchott\",\"Africa\\/Ouagadougou\",\"Africa\\/Porto-Novo\",\"Africa\\/Sao_Tome\",\"Africa\\/Tripoli\",\"Africa\\/Tunis\",\"Africa\\/Windhoek\",\"America\\/Adak\",\"America\\/Anchorage\",\"America\\/Anguilla\",\"America\\/Antigua\",\"America\\/Araguaina\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Buenos_Aires\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Catamarca\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Cordoba\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Jujuy\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/La_Rioja\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Mendoza\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Rio_Gallegos\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Salta\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/San_Juan\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/San_Luis\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Tucuman\",\"America\\/Argentina\\/Ushuaia\",\"America\\/Aruba\",\"America\\/Asuncion\",\"America\\/Atikokan\",\"America\\/Bahia\",\"America\\/Bahia_Banderas\",\"America\\/Barbados\",\"America\\/Belem\",\"America\\/Belize\",\"America\\/Blanc-Sablon\",\"America\\/Boa_Vista\",\"America\\/Bogota\",\"America\\/Boise\",\"America\\/Cambridge_Bay\",\"America\\/Campo_Grande\",\"America\\/Cancun\",\"America\\/Caracas\",\"America\\/Cayenne\",\"America\\/Cayman\",\"America\\/Chicago\",\"America\\/Chihuahua\",\"America\\/Costa_Rica\",\"America\\/Creston\",\"America\\/Cuiaba\",\"America\\/Curacao\",\"America\\/Danmarkshavn\",\"America\\/Dawson\",\"America\\/Dawson_Creek\",\"America\\/Denver\",\"America\\/Detroit\",\"America\\/Dominica\",\"America\\/Edmonton\",\"America\\/Eirunepe\",\"America\\/El_Salvador\",\"America\\/Fort_Nelson\",\"America\\/Fortaleza\",\"America\\/Glace_Bay\",\"America\\/Goose_Bay\",\"America\\/Grand_Turk\",\"America\\/Grenada\",\"America\\/Guadeloupe\",\"America\\/Guatemala\",\"America\\/Guayaquil\",\"America\\/Guyana\",\"America\\/Halifax\",\"America\\/Havana\",\"America\\/Hermosillo\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Indianapolis\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Knox\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Marengo\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Petersburg\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Tell_City\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Vevay\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Vincennes\",\"America\\/Indiana\\/Winamac\",\"America\\/Inuvik\",\"America\\/Iqaluit\",\"America\\/Jamaica\",\"America\\/Juneau\",\"America\\/Kentucky\\/Louisville\",\"America\\/Kentucky\\/Monticello\",\"America\\/Kralendijk\",\"America\\/La_Paz\",\"America\\/Lima\",\"America\\/Los_Angeles\",\"America\\/Lower_Princes\",\"America\\/Maceio\",\"America\\/Managua\",\"America\\/Manaus\",\"America\\/Marigot\",\"America\\/Martinique\",\"America\\/Matamoros\",\"America\\/Mazatlan\",\"America\\/Menominee\",\"America\\/Merida\",\"America\\/Metlakatla\",\"America\\/Mexico_City\",\"America\\/Miquelon\",\"America\\/Moncton\",\"America\\/Monterrey\",\"America\\/Montevideo\",\"America\\/Montserrat\",\"America\\/Nassau\",\"America\\/New_York\",\"America\\/Nipigon\",\"America\\/Nome\",\"America\\/Noronha\",\"America\\/North_Dakota\\/Beulah\",\"America\\/North_Dakota\\/Center\",\"America\\/North_Dakota\\/New_Salem\",\"America\\/Nuuk\",\"America\\/Ojinaga\",\"America\\/Panama\",\"America\\/Pangnirtung\",\"America\\/Paramaribo\",\"America\\/Phoenix\",\"America\\/Port-au-Prince\",\"America\\/Port_of_Spain\",\"America\\/Porto_Velho\",\"America\\/Puerto_Rico\",\"America\\/Punta_Arenas\",\"America\\/Rainy_River\",\"America\\/Rankin_Inlet\",\"America\\/Recife\",\"America\\/Regina\",\"America\\/Resolute\",\"America\\/Rio_Branco\",\"America\\/Santarem\",\"America\\/Santiago\",\"America\\/Santo_Domingo\",\"America\\/Sao_Paulo\",\"America\\/Scoresbysund\",\"America\\/Sitka\",\"America\\/St_Barthelemy\",\"America\\/St_Johns\",\"America\\/St_Kitts\",\"America\\/St_Lucia\",\"America\\/St_Thomas\",\"America\\/St_Vincent\",\"America\\/Swift_Current\",\"America\\/Tegucigalpa\",\"America\\/Thule\",\"America\\/Thunder_Bay\",\"America\\/Tijuana\",\"America\\/Toronto\",\"America\\/Tortola\",\"America\\/Vancouver\",\"America\\/Whitehorse\",\"America\\/Winnipeg\",\"America\\/Yakutat\",\"America\\/Yellowknife\",\"Antarctica\\/Casey\",\"Antarctica\\/Davis\",\"Antarctica\\/DumontDUrville\",\"Antarctica\\/Macquarie\",\"Antarctica\\/Mawson\",\"Antarctica\\/McMurdo\",\"Antarctica\\/Palmer\",\"Antarctica\\/Rothera\",\"Antarctica\\/Syowa\",\"Antarctica\\/Troll\",\"Antarctica\\/Vostok\",\"Arctic\\/Longyearbyen\",\"Asia\\/Aden\",\"Asia\\/Almaty\",\"Asia\\/Amman\",\"Asia\\/Anadyr\",\"Asia\\/Aqtau\",\"Asia\\/Aqtobe\",\"Asia\\/Ashgabat\",\"Asia\\/Atyrau\",\"Asia\\/Baghdad\",\"Asia\\/Bahrain\",\"Asia\\/Baku\",\"Asia\\/Bangkok\",\"Asia\\/Barnaul\",\"Asia\\/Beirut\",\"Asia\\/Bishkek\",\"Asia\\/Brunei\",\"Asia\\/Chita\",\"Asia\\/Choibalsan\",\"Asia\\/Colombo\",\"Asia\\/Damascus\",\"Asia\\/Dhaka\",\"Asia\\/Dili\",\"Asia\\/Dubai\",\"Asia\\/Dushanbe\",\"Asia\\/Famagusta\",\"Asia\\/Gaza\",\"Asia\\/Hebron\",\"Asia\\/Ho_Chi_Minh\",\"Asia\\/Hong_Kong\",\"Asia\\/Hovd\",\"Asia\\/Irkutsk\",\"Asia\\/Jakarta\",\"Asia\\/Jayapura\",\"Asia\\/Jerusalem\",\"Asia\\/Kabul\",\"Asia\\/Kamchatka\",\"Asia\\/Karachi\",\"Asia\\/Kathmandu\",\"Asia\\/Khandyga\",\"Asia\\/Kolkata\",\"Asia\\/Krasnoyarsk\",\"Asia\\/Kuala_Lumpur\",\"Asia\\/Kuching\",\"Asia\\/Kuwait\",\"Asia\\/Macau\",\"Asia\\/Magadan\",\"Asia\\/Makassar\",\"Asia\\/Manila\",\"Asia\\/Muscat\",\"Asia\\/Nicosia\",\"Asia\\/Novokuznetsk\",\"Asia\\/Novosibirsk\",\"Asia\\/Omsk\",\"Asia\\/Oral\",\"Asia\\/Phnom_Penh\",\"Asia\\/Pontianak\",\"Asia\\/Pyongyang\",\"Asia\\/Qatar\",\"Asia\\/Qostanay\",\"Asia\\/Qyzylorda\",\"Asia\\/Riyadh\",\"Asia\\/Sakhalin\",\"Asia\\/Samarkand\",\"Asia\\/Seoul\",\"Asia\\/Shanghai\",\"Asia\\/Singapore\",\"Asia\\/Srednekolymsk\",\"Asia\\/Taipei\",\"Asia\\/Tashkent\",\"Asia\\/Tbilisi\",\"Asia\\/Tehran\",\"Asia\\/Thimphu\",\"Asia\\/Tokyo\",\"Asia\\/Tomsk\",\"Asia\\/Ulaanbaatar\",\"Asia\\/Urumqi\",\"Asia\\/Ust-Nera\",\"Asia\\/Vientiane\",\"Asia\\/Vladivostok\",\"Asia\\/Yakutsk\",\"Asia\\/Yangon\",\"Asia\\/Yekaterinburg\",\"Asia\\/Yerevan\",\"Atlantic\\/Azores\",\"Atlantic\\/Bermuda\",\"Atlantic\\/Canary\",\"Atlantic\\/Cape_Verde\",\"Atlantic\\/Faroe\",\"Atlantic\\/Madeira\",\"Atlantic\\/Reykjavik\",\"Atlantic\\/South_Georgia\",\"Atlantic\\/St_Helena\",\"Atlantic\\/Stanley\",\"Australia\\/Adelaide\",\"Australia\\/Brisbane\",\"Australia\\/Broken_Hill\",\"Australia\\/Darwin\",\"Australia\\/Eucla\",\"Australia\\/Hobart\",\"Australia\\/Lindeman\",\"Australia\\/Lord_Howe\",\"Australia\\/Melbourne\",\"Australia\\/Perth\",\"Australia\\/Sydney\",\"Europe\\/Amsterdam\",\"Europe\\/Andorra\",\"Europe\\/Astrakhan\",\"Europe\\/Athens\",\"Europe\\/Belgrade\",\"Europe\\/Berlin\",\"Europe\\/Bratislava\",\"Europe\\/Brussels\",\"Europe\\/Bucharest\",\"Europe\\/Budapest\",\"Europe\\/Busingen\",\"Europe\\/Chisinau\",\"Europe\\/Copenhagen\",\"Europe\\/Dublin\",\"Europe\\/Gibraltar\",\"Europe\\/Guernsey\",\"Europe\\/Helsinki\",\"Europe\\/Isle_of_Man\",\"Europe\\/Istanbul\",\"Europe\\/Jersey\",\"Europe\\/Kaliningrad\",\"Europe\\/Kiev\",\"Europe\\/Kirov\",\"Europe\\/Lisbon\",\"Europe\\/Ljubljana\",\"Europe\\/London\",\"Europe\\/Luxembourg\",\"Europe\\/Madrid\",\"Europe\\/Malta\",\"Europe\\/Mariehamn\",\"Europe\\/Minsk\",\"Europe\\/Monaco\",\"Europe\\/Moscow\",\"Europe\\/Oslo\",\"Europe\\/Paris\",\"Europe\\/Podgorica\",\"Europe\\/Prague\",\"Europe\\/Riga\",\"Europe\\/Rome\",\"Europe\\/Samara\",\"Europe\\/San_Marino\",\"Europe\\/Sarajevo\",\"Europe\\/Saratov\",\"Europe\\/Simferopol\",\"Europe\\/Skopje\",\"Europe\\/Sofia\",\"Europe\\/Stockholm\",\"Europe\\/Tallinn\",\"Europe\\/Tirane\",\"Europe\\/Ulyanovsk\",\"Europe\\/Uzhgorod\",\"Europe\\/Vaduz\",\"Europe\\/Vatican\",\"Europe\\/Vienna\",\"Europe\\/Vilnius\",\"Europe\\/Volgograd\",\"Europe\\/Warsaw\",\"Europe\\/Zagreb\",\"Europe\\/Zaporozhye\",\"Europe\\/Zurich\",\"Indian\\/Antananarivo\",\"Indian\\/Chagos\",\"Indian\\/Christmas\",\"Indian\\/Cocos\",\"Indian\\/Comoro\",\"Indian\\/Kerguelen\",\"Indian\\/Mahe\",\"Indian\\/Maldives\",\"Indian\\/Mauritius\",\"Indian\\/Mayotte\",\"Indian\\/Reunion\",\"Pacific\\/Apia\",\"Pacific\\/Auckland\",\"Pacific\\/Bougainville\",\"Pacific\\/Chatham\",\"Pacific\\/Chuuk\",\"Pacific\\/Easter\",\"Pacific\\/Efate\",\"Pacific\\/Enderbury\",\"Pacific\\/Fakaofo\",\"Pacific\\/Fiji\",\"Pacific\\/Funafuti\",\"Pacific\\/Galapagos\",\"Pacific\\/Gambier\",\"Pacific\\/Guadalcanal\",\"Pacific\\/Guam\",\"Pacific\\/Honolulu\",\"Pacific\\/Kiritimati\",\"Pacific\\/Kosrae\",\"Pacific\\/Kwajalein\",\"Pacific\\/Majuro\",\"Pacific\\/Marquesas\",\"Pacific\\/Midway\",\"Pacific\\/Nauru\",\"Pacific\\/Niue\",\"Pacific\\/Norfolk\",\"Pacific\\/Noumea\",\"Pacific\\/Pago_Pago\",\"Pacific\\/Palau\",\"Pacific\\/Pitcairn\",\"Pacific\\/Pohnpei\",\"Pacific\\/Port_Moresby\",\"Pacific\\/Rarotonga\",\"Pacific\\/Saipan\",\"Pacific\\/Tahiti\",\"Pacific\\/Tarawa\",\"Pacific\\/Tongatapu\",\"Pacific\\/Wake\",\"Pacific\\/Wallis\",\"UTC\"]")
const localTimezones = this.$moment.tz.names()

for (const [index, timezone] of localTimezones.entries()) {
  if (!prodTimezones.includes(timezone)) {
    console.log(timezone)
  }
}
```

And the attached missing timezones from PHP? There's a lot more, but here's some

[image: timezones]

Comment: The 'missing' time zones aren't missing at all. Moment.js just has some synonyms added. For example, US/Hawaii appears in the PHP list as Pacific/Honolulu, US/Alaska is America/Juneau, and so on. Some of the synonyms are more intuitive than the PHP version, but there are no time zones actually missing.

Comment: Great news, what do you suggest for the timezone validation rule then? For instance, if Moment JS picks `US/Central`, then this is treated as invalid by Laravel's validation rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thing called [tz, zoneinfo, or the Olson database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). It's maintained by the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)

It names zones in `Continent/City` or sometimes `Continent/State/City` format, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `America/Indiana/Knox`. Each named zone contains rules for converting to and from UTC time to local time, including the correct handling of summer time.

The database contains the temporopolitical history of time zone and summer time changeovers for the city (and surrounding regions). So, if the government of, say, Knox Indiana USA, changes the summer time rules next year, their entry gets updated in a maintenance release of the database.

If Spain decides to repudiate its Franco-era decision to use the same time zone as 'Europe/Berlin', and move to the same zone as 'Europe/Lisbon', the updated zoneinfo data for 'Europe/Madrid' will reflect that change on its effective date. Updates to UNIX-based operating systems like Linux and MacOS include the most recent zoneinfo data.

php uses zoneinfo. So does MySql. moment.js adds synonyms to it. If somebody in Knox sets their time zone to moment's synonym 'US/Central' and the city council the changes the rules, they won't follow the change.

So, please consider using php's list in your application, because it's proven so far to be future-proof.

Comment: So is the general suggestion from this then to limit the time zones from Moment JS and try to get the ones from Moment to match the ones offered by PHP? I've done this by exporting the ones from PHP, and have got a loop on the Moment ones to compare with the PHP ones, and if they don't match it skips to the next to build up a list for the front-end. Similar with with the `tz.guess()`

Comment: Moment also uses the same database.  The "synonyms" you're talking about are `Link` entries in the tzdb.  PHP supports them also.

Answer (score 1):

Per the PHP [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php), the full form of `timezone_identifiers_list` is:

```php
timezone_identifiers_list ( int $timezoneGroup = DateTimeZone::ALL , string|null $countryCode = null ) : array
```

By default, the `$timezoneGroup` parameter is [`DateTimeZone::ALL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php#datetimezone.constants.all), which is designed to return only the `Zone` entries from the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

If you want to really return *all* valid time zone identifiers, then you need to also consider the `Link` entries in the IANA time zone database, which are established for backwards compatibility purposes.  In PHP, you can pass the [`DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php#datetimezone.constants.all-with-bc) constant to get the entire list of `Zone` and `Link` identifiers.

```php
// get all time zone identifiers, including backwards compatible.
$timezone_identifiers = timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC);
```

Or using the object-oriented style `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`:

```php
// get all time zone identifiers, including backwards compatible.
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC);
```

The list should mostly align with the one you get from Moment-Timezone.

I'll also point out that if at all possible you should consider using a different library than Moment and/or Moment-Timezone. Please read [Moment's Project Status Page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for more details.  Thanks.